# MySQL Update Stock set + or - according to amount inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Every product sold is inserted to a table with ID CODE QUANTITY PRICE ETC and the product by CODE is also updated from table STOCK
Example
STOCK QUANTITY 5 I sell now 3 those 3 gets disccounted from STOCK so now I have only 2 left in STOCK

What if I need to edit the sale? well we retrieve the sale to a EDIT SALE form autofilling everything like

```
QUANTITY 3 MAKE SAMSUNG MODEL TEWTWE34 PRICE 50.9
```

Untill there everything ok but what if I just need to change the QUANTITY?
Remember the quantity already got disccounted from STOCK so if I change I need to

```
    $code= mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['code']);
    $quantity= mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['quantity']);
    $edit = mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE products
    SET stock = stock + $quantity WHERE code = $code");
```

And also update the sale

The problem I have is here

```
SET stock = stock + $quantity
```

If the sale was 3 then we do not update stock, but if we modify to 2 then we must sum (add) 1 to STOCK
If we update in form to 7 then we do must take 4 more from STOCK

the only way I see it to be solved may be by using a PHP like this

```
IF $quantity >3 = else if <3 else
```

If there any other easy way maybe just with MySQL or some simple PHP code?

Thanks for any help